# Ground State calculation for defined 2D Ising Model with tensor networks

Tags: quantum-information, hamiltonian, ising-model, ground-state, tensor-network

I have a Hamiltonian and 2D spin-lattice system. I am trying to find a ground state configuration. Spin interactions are long-ranged so I am trying to use PEPS to approximate. My question is this:

Which library from python is let me define a hamiltonian from stretch and has a function for PEPS routine and auto grad (for optimize over)?

I am also open to using Mathematica/Matlab kind of environments for this task but it has gotta be with **tensor networks**.

Also, I have been studying the Hamiltonian for some time and I might be able to reduce the dimension into 1D and use MPS and DMRG. In fact, solving this in 1D has seemed to be a better option but I am open to any kind of help and advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've heard good things about Itensor (https://itensor.org/) but that requires Julia/C++ tho Julia is sort of similar to Python I suppose

Comment: @Wihtedeka thank you will check that.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the most luck [easily constructing PEPS Hamiltonians in QUIMB](https://quimb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensor-2d.html?highlight=PEPS#Specifying-2D-Hamiltonians). It also has plenty of [pre-built Hamiltonians](https://quimb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/quimb.tensor.tensor_gen.html#quimb.tensor.tensor_gen.ham_2d_ising). As for autograd - [it's got that too](https://quimb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ex_tensorflow_optimize_pbc_mps.html). It's a python package, and probably my favorite tensor networks package ever. I use it every day - not sure why it doesn't get mentioned more.